# How to get all customers data from Shopify Python API?

Tags: python, pandas, shopify

For a private Shopify app, I want to retrieve all the customers data and write into a csv file. I have tried the option below for getting page-wise 250 records at a time. But I am getting an error:
HTTPError: Bad Request

```
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)  
import sys  
import pandas as pd  


% Get all customers  
def get_all_resources(resource, **kwargs):  
resource_count = resource.count(**kwargs)  
resources = []  
if resource_count > 0:  
    for page in range(1, ((resource_count-1) // 250) + 2):  
        kwargs.update({"limit" : 250, "page" : page})  
        resources.extend(resource.find(**kwargs))    
return resources  

all_customers = get_all_resources(shopify.Customer)  
data=[]  
for customer in all_customers:  
  tempdata=[]  
  tempdata.append(customer.id)  
  tempdata.append(customer.first_name)  
  tempdata.append(customer.last_name)  
  tempdata.append(customer.addresses)  
  tempdata.append(customer.phone)  
  tempdata.append(customer.email)  
  data.append(tempdata)  

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['CustomerCode','FirstName','LastName','Address','MobileNo','Email'])  
df.to_csv('CustomerDataFromServer.csv',index=False)  

shopify.ShopifyResource.clear_session()
```

Comment: It would help if you were more specific about which line is raising the error. I'm not familiar with the shopify API, but would wonder if `resource_count = resource.count(**kwargs)` works when `kwargs` is empty? What's the point in `kwargs` in that function anyway - it's aonly called once, with one arg, so `kwargs` is always empty. Might be better to use a dictionary local to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot use page-based pagination](https://shopify.dev/changelog/page-based-pagination-replaced-by-cursor-based-pagination-across-multiple-rest-endpoints) anymore.

Use [cursor-based pagination](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/make-paginated-requests-to-rest-admin-api) instead.